# IE not reading cookie despite privacy settings set to enable all cookies

Tags: php, cookies

I have a small test page which prints all cookies and if $_COOKIE['TEST'] is not set then it creates the cookie record.

```
<?php

if (!isset($_COOKIE['TEST']) ) {
    $now = time();
    setcookie("TEST", $now, $now+2592000);
}
else { 
    print_r($_COOKIE);
}
?>
```

This works fine on Chrome, and on IE 8 for 3 other PCs I have tested. 
The first time the page is viewed the browser creates a cookie. On the second visit it prints the record. Output is something like this:

> Array ( [TEST] => 1366214517 )

However on one PC with IE8 this doesn't work. I am worried that the issue could occur for others. On the machine with the problem:

- The privacy settings are set to Low
- I have also specifically allowed cookie for this site under Privacy >
  Sites following these steps:
  http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows-vista/block-or-allow-cookies
- Under View > Webpage Privacy Policy the Privacy Report says "Based on
  your privacy settings, no cookies were restricted or blocked." It
  says Cookies are Accepted
- I have checked the PC time with JavaScript vs PHP for server time and both are in-line (when testing with a larger page with a cookie expire)

I would appreciate any insight on this question.

Many thanks.

**Update** I added an expiry to cookie

**Update 2** If I remove set cookie from the first if statement (when cookies should have already been saved in a previous page view) then IE developer tools shows no record of the cookie. With set cookie back in it prints the following message:

> NAME  TEST
>   VALUE  1366271544
>   DOMAIN  www.myexamplewebsite.com
>   PATH 
>   /
>   EXPIRES  18/05/2013 08:52:24

Comment: use the IE dev tools (`f12`) to see if the cookie makes it to the browser at all.

Comment: thx - i added an expiry which was missing from my test. The cookie cache shows the cookie as existing.

Comment: hi, no the problem still persists. I tried another couple of computers  and it works fine, just not on one. I also tried making IE the default browser to see if that would work, no luck.

Comment: sorry I was mistaken yesterday evening - removing the set cookie from the script after it should have already stored a cookie (on a previous page load) and it shows no record of it in the dev tools, updated above